# Maximum value of the lowest sum in a set of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, contest-math

Last year in a maths contest held in Catalonia called [Cangur](http://www.cangur.org/) it was posed the following qüestion:

> We write numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10, in a certain order around a circumference. Then we sum each number with its two neighbors and we get 10 sums. Which is the maximum value that can have the lowest of these sums?
>   
>   a) 14      
>   b) 15      
>   c) 16      
>   d) 17      
>   e) 18

My first approach has been to add up all the triplets. By doing that, I will get a number that won't change independently from the order of the numbers around the circumference.

$$
(1+2+3)+(2+3+4)+(3+4+5)+\dots+(10+1+2)=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} 3n=165
$$

Therefore, I can deduce that the average sum of every triplet is $16.5$ which automatically discards $17$ and $18$ from being the correct answer. That's because if one of the triplets added up $17$, in order to keep the average at $16.5$, we would need some other triplet to add up less than $17$, which would imply that this triplet adding up $17$ wasn't the lowest triplet. And the same explanation would work for $18$.

I can also discard $16$ because in order to keep the average at $16.5$ we would need more or half of the triplets to add up $16$. And, although I'm not 100% sure about this assertion, I think it can be proven that there aren't 5 possible ways of adding up $16$ that can be written around the circumference.

In any case, even if my last guess was true, I'm not sure how to proceed at this point. I don't know how to choose between $14$ and $15$ and I don't like to think that the only way of finding the correct answer is to try out and see if it works. So if some of you have found any other ways of facing the problem I'd really appreciate it if you shared it. Thanks!

**Edit**: In order to understand better what I meant by these 10 sums of triplets, here's a sketch that shows that visually for the first three sums. I would also want to make clear that the order of the numbers in the drawing isn't the order in which they should be to solve the problem.
[image: Sums]

Comment: sorry what does mean 10 sums?

Comment: I mean that as there are 10 triplets, there are 10 sums. For instance, if the sequence wasn't disordered, these ten sums would be each of the parenthesis that I've written to explain my approach. I'm not sure if I explain myself really well in English, I hope you understand it better now.

Comment: i did not understand sorry,could you show using   visually

Comment: Ok, wait a second. I'll try to show it visually!

Comment: @datodatuashvili I've just edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower sum cannot be greater that $16.5$. So the lower sum can be less or equal than 16.
If it was 16 then we must have 5 sums equal to 16 and the other 5 equal to 17 something that cannot be achieved.

Maximum lower sum equal to 15 can be achieved: 1 6 8 3 7 5 9 2 4 10 around the circle

Hence the answer is 15.

Comment: I used the same argument to discard 16. In any case, to choose between 14 and 15 what has been your methodology? You've just tried to see if it worked with 15?

Comment: In order to find the maximum lowest sum you need some configuration of the form: 8 * * 10 * * 9 *  7 * more or less in order to "hide" the small numbers 1,2,3 among the bigger ones. Then you try filling up the missing numbers in pairs trying to keep the average. Easily you can achieve 15.
In some sense, yes, I tried to see if 15 can be achieved since I was suspecting that 15 can be achieved.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But I'm thinking what would happen if instead of numbers from 1 to 10, there were from 1 to 100. Do you think there's some way of approaching it that could work for any of the cases?

Comment: For 100 numbers it will be difficult to find a configuration to show that some specific number is achieved as a maximum lower sum.
So in this case a more general approach is needed.
But for 10 numbers showing how 15 can be achieved is the easiest way, that's why I wrote that solution.